# how to get 64 bit integer in common lisp?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, bit, clisp

I want to write a bitboard in common lisp, so I need a 64 bit integer. How do I get a 64 bit integer in common lisp? Also, are there any libraries that could help me accomplish this without writing everything from scratch?

Comment: Which Lisp implementation are you using?

Comment: Which CL implementation? Try evaluating the following two forms in the REPL: `(lisp-implementation-type)` and `(lisp-implementation-version)`.

Comment: With CLISP, its largest *fixnum* on a 64-bit core is (2^48)-1, which implies that six or seven bits per 32-bit word are used as tags. The immediate object representation discussion in the implementation notes confirms this: http://clisp.org/impnotes.html#immediate-o Also, see: http://clisp.org/impnotes.html#fixnum-lim

Comment: I wonder, why INTEL and AMD have not yet picked up on all those "type tag" idioms (also used in ML dialects) and finally give us a 70-bit architecture, so we can have a tagged 64 bit value in high level languages... :)

Answer (score 7):

You can declare your variables to be of type `(signed-byte 64)` or `(unsigned-byte 64)`:

```
CL-USER> (typexpand '(unsigned-byte 64))
(INTEGER 0 18446744073709551615)
T
CL-USER> (typexpand '(signed-byte 64))
(INTEGER -9223372036854775808 9223372036854775807)
T
```

It depends upon your implementation if it is actually clever enough to really stuff this in 8 consecutive bytes or if it will use a bignum for this. Appropriate `optimize`-declarations might help.

Here's a (very simple) example of such type declarations, and handling integers in binary:

```
(let* ((x #b01)
       (y #b10)
       (z (logior x y)))
  (declare ((signed-byte 64) x y z))
  (format t "~a~%" (logbitp 1 x))
  (format t "~a~%" (logbitp 1 (logior x (ash 1 1))))
  (format t "~b~%" z))

Output:
NIL
T
11
```

Here's a setf-expander definition to get a simple setter for bits in integers, and a corresponding getter:

```
(define-setf-expander logbit (index place &environment env)
  (multiple-value-bind (temps vals stores store-form access-form)
      (get-setf-expansion place env)
    (let ((i (gensym))
          (store (gensym))
          (stemp (first stores)))
      (values `(,i ,@temps)
              `(,index ,@vals)
              `(,store)
              `(let ((,stemp (dpb ,store (byte 1 ,i) ,access-form))
                     ,@(cdr stores))
                 ,store-form
                 ,store)
              `(logbit ,i ,access-form)))))

(defun logbit (index integer)
  (ldb (byte 1 index) integer))
```

These can be used like this:

```
(let ((x 1))
  (setf (logbit 3 x) 1)
  x)
==> 9
(let ((x 9))
  (setf (logbit 3 x) 0)
  x)
==> 1

(logbit 3 1)
==> 0
(logbit 3 9)
==> 1
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more? I am using common lisp 2.48 and when I typed (signed-byte 64) I got an error back

Comment: `(signed-byte 64)` is a type specifier, not a function. It may only be used where a type specifier is legal. I've added an example to my answer.

Comment: I've expanded the example. You can use `logbitp` to check for individual bits, and a combination of `logior` and `ash` to set them.

Comment: Or an alternative way to set bits is `(setf (ldb (byte 1 pos) int) 1)`, as in this example: `(let ((x 0)) (setf (ldb (byte 1 2) x) 1) x)` ==> `2`.

Comment: What difference does (signed-byte 64) make? I have tried (defvar x 3 ((signed-byte 64) x)) and (defvar y 3), they both seem to behave the same way.

Comment: Type declarations in Common Lisp are hints to the compiler. Common Lisp integer are always unbounded, but large ones will be stored in an inefficient format with pointers (bignums). The efficient, primitive integers (fixnums) will usually be less than 64bit on 64bit systems because some bits are used for type tags. The compiler may use the type declarations to get rid of the type tags and use full 64bit primitive integers.

Comment: I've just seen that Rainer's answer provides some valuable points about this. He's right, and I've mentioned this in my answer, too, it depends upon your implementation and is not defined by the standard if the type declaration will make any difference. If you don't actually need the full 64bits, you could also make do with regular fixnums that don't need a type declaration. Though I've just checked and fixnums are only 48bits for 64bit CLISP (as opposed to 62bit for 64bit SBCL).

Comment: For that (setf (ldb (byte 1 2) x) 1) x) function. How come when I defined it to be (defun setBit (bitboard i) (setf (ldb (byte 1 i) bitboard) 1)) there is no effect?

Comment: Because Common Lisp functions use pass-by-value, i.e. changing your argument variable bitboard does not change the original variable, but only a copy local to your function.

Comment: If you want to manipulate a variable with an operator of your own, you need a macro. I've added a suitable setf-expander definition to my answer.

Comment: is define-setf-expander a macro? All examples I saw use defmacro.

Comment: `define-setf-expander` itself is of course a macro (just like `defun`), but what I think you really mean: no, the definitions created by `define-setf-expander`, the setf expanders, are not macros themselves, but are helper functions for the macro `setf`.

Comment: What is the difference between the first logbit and the second logbit?

Comment: The version defined with `define-setf-expander` is for setting bits with `setf`, the version defined with `defun` is a simple function for reading bits.

Comment: Not to discount Rords work here, but you should really look at Mirons entry. The problem is that you have a preconceived notion of how this should be done, how it should be represented. Yet Mirons example show how you can manipulate the bit board as a simple array (aref bit-board x y), and let the compiler deal with the actual representation in memory. With the proper declarations the compiler will do the best it can. CLISP, specifically, runs against a byte code and you will likely never get to a 64-bit integer. But Miron shows how to do this and ignore all the bit operations yourself.

Answer (score 6):

In portable Common Lisp 'Integers' are as large as you like. There is a more efficient subset of integers called 'fixnums'. The exact range of fixnums is implementation depended. But it is typically not the full 64 bit (on a 64bit architecture) which can be used, since most Common Lisp implementations need type tag bits. For the user there is not much of a difference. Fixnums are a subset of integers and one can add two fixnums and get a not-fixnum integer result. The only differences that may be observable is that computation with non-fixnum integers is slower, needs more storage, ... Generally, if you want to do computation with integers, you don't need to declare that you want to calculate with 64bit. You just use Integers and the usual operations for those.

If you want real 64bit large integers (represented in only 64bits, without tags, etc.) and computation with those, you'll leave the portable ANSI CL capabilities. If and how CLISP supports that, is best asked on the CLISP mailing list.

Documentation

- Type [FIXNUM](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/t_fixnum.htm#fixnum)
- Type [INTEGER](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/t_intege.htm#integer)

Answer (score 6):

Example usage of bit vectors/arrays to implement a 8x8 bit-board
(starting with brutally and prematurely optimized code just to show a
way to get tight assembler code):

```
(defun make-bitboard ()
  (make-array '(8 8) :element-type '(mod 2) :initial-element 0))
```

`MAKE-BITBOARD` will create a 8x8 bitboard as an array of bits. When
using SBCL, this is internally represented as 1 bit per element (so
you have 64 bits + array instance overhead). If you ask for
optimizations when accessing the board, you'll get fast code.

```
(declaim (inline get-bitboard))
(defun get-bitboard (bit-board x y)
       (declare (optimize speed (safety 0) (debug 0))
                (type (simple-array (mod 2) (8 8)) bit-board)
                (type fixnum x y))
       (aref bit-board x y))
(declaim (notinline get-bitboard))
```

The `DECLAIM`s are there to allow local
[inlining requests](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/d_inline.htm) for
`GET-BITBOARD`.

An example of using `GET-BITBOARD`:

```
(defun use-bitboard (bit-board)
  (declare (optimize speed (safety 0) (debug 0))
           (type (simple-array (mod 2) (8 8)) bit-board)
           (inline get-bitboard))
  (let ((sum 0))
    (declare (type fixnum sum))
    (dotimes (i 8)
      (declare (type fixnum i))
      (dotimes (j 8)
        (declare (type fixnum j))
        (incf sum (the (mod 2) (get-bitboard bit-board i j)))))
    sum))
```

Since there is no `SET-BITBOARD` yet, an example of using `USE-BITBOARD` is:

```
(use-bitboard (make-bitboard))
```

Disassembling `USE-BITBOARD` (SBCL again, Linux x64) shows that the
compiler inlined `GET-BITBOARD`:

```
; disassembly for USE-BITBOARD
; 030F96A2:       31F6             XOR ESI, ESI               ; no-arg-parsing entry point
;      6A4:       31D2             XOR EDX, EDX
;      6A6:       EB54             JMP L3
;      6A8:       90               NOP
;      6A9:       90               NOP
;      6AA:       90               NOP
;      6AB:       90               NOP
;      6AC:       90               NOP
;      6AD:       90               NOP
;      6AE:       90               NOP
;      6AF:       90               NOP
;      6B0: L0:   31DB             XOR EBX, EBX
;      6B2:       EB3E             JMP L2
;      6B4:       90               NOP
;      6B5:       90               NOP
;      6B6:       90               NOP
;      6B7:       90               NOP
;      6B8:       90               NOP
;      6B9:       90               NOP
;      6BA:       90               NOP
;      6BB:       90               NOP
;      6BC:       90               NOP
;      6BD:       90               NOP
;      6BE:       90               NOP
;      6BF:       90               NOP
;      6C0: L1:   488D04D500000000 LEA RAX, [RDX*8]
;      6C8:       4801D8           ADD RAX, RBX
;      6CB:       4C8B4711         MOV R8, [RDI+17]
;      6CF:       48D1F8           SAR RAX, 1
;      6D2:       488BC8           MOV RCX, RAX
;      6D5:       48C1E906         SHR RCX, 6
;      6D9:       4D8B44C801       MOV R8, [R8+RCX*8+1]
;      6DE:       488BC8           MOV RCX, RAX
;      6E1:       49D3E8           SHR R8, CL
;      6E4:       4983E001         AND R8, 1
;      6E8:       49D1E0           SHL R8, 1
;      6EB:       4C01C6           ADD RSI, R8
;      6EE:       4883C302         ADD RBX, 2
;      6F2: L2:   4883FB10         CMP RBX, 16
;      6F6:       7CC8             JL L1
;      6F8:       4883C202         ADD RDX, 2
;      6FC: L3:   4883FA10         CMP RDX, 16
;      700:       7CAE             JL L0
;      702:       488BD6           MOV RDX, RSI
;      705:       488BE5           MOV RSP, RBP
;      708:       F8               CLC
;      709:       5D               POP RBP
;      70A:       C3               RET
```

Not sure why the compiler put in all those `NOP`s (leaving space for
instrumentation later? alignments?) but if you look at the code at the
end it's pretty compact (not as compact as hand-crafted assembler, of
course).

Now this is an obvious case of premature optimization. The correct way
to start here would be to simply write:

```
(defun get-bitboard (bit-board x y)
  (aref bit-board x y))

(defun use-bitboard (bit-board)
  (let ((sum 0))
    (dotimes (i 8)
      (dotimes (j 8)
        (incf sum (get-bitboard bit-board i j))))
    sum))
```

... and then use a profiler when running the game code that uses the
bit-board to see where the CPU bottlenecks are. SBCL includes a nice
[statistical profiler](http://www.sbcl.org/manual/Statistical-Profiler.html).

Starting with the simpler and slower code, with no declarations for
speed, is best. Just compare the size of the code - I started with the
code with plenty of declarations to make the simple code at the end
look even simpler by comparison :-). The advantage here is that you
can treat Common Lisp as a scripting/prototyping language when trying
out ideas, then squeeze more performance out of the code that the
profiler suggests.

The assembly code is obviously not as tight as loading the whole board in
one 64 bit register and then accessing individual bits. But if you
suddenly decide that you want more than 1 bit per square, it's much
easier to change the CL code than to change assembler code (just
change the array type everywhere from `'(mod 2)` to `'(mod 16)`, for
instance).

Comment: What about using integers instead of bit-vectors? What is the difference like? which one is faster?

Comment: The problem is that the CL spec doesn't give you fixnums of a guaranteed size - at 64bit you'll get a bignum on most implementations today (32 bit implementations - too small, obviously, 64 bit implementations - they use a couple bits for tagging). So you end up with bignums, or you could split the 64 bit fixnum in 4 16 bit fixnums and go from there. As for 'faster', this depends on implementation, optimizations used etc. Measure it! Personally, I don't think in terms of 'fast' and 'slow', but 'fast enough' and 'too slow' - this forces me to answer the 'for what?' question, which is good IMO.

Comment: As for speed, try writing bignum functions similar to what I wrote  (hints on how to do that in other replies), and compare assembly code. IMO this is better than timing code (it's still pretty useless without a more meaningful prototype). The only meaningful (IMO) benchmark would be on a prototype of your code. Again, if I were you, I'd go with bitvectors. Isolating the bitboard code behind an  interface means that it's easy to change the bitboard implementation later should it become necessary.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use bit vectors, which are arbitrary sized arrays of bits, rather than something like a 64 bit integer. The implementation will deal with the internal representations for you.

Comment: Is manipulating bit vectors as fast as 64 bit integers? Also how come I can't access a 64 bit integer in lisp? Is it because it depends on implementation?